# Desperately in need of help

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

So I made a huge mistake and I am in desperate need of help.  I had installed Ubuntu 12.04 along side Windows 7.  I was planning on switching over so I figured I would copy over all my pictures, music, and other files to my new Ubuntu partition and then delete Windows.  I had figured Ubuntu created a separate partition on my hard drive which had nothing to do with Windows so I went ahead and deleted the Windows partitions.

I didn't realize this would destroy my Ubuntu installation as well.  When I go to install Windows again with the disc I can see the partition that was created for Ubuntu, but all it shows is free space.  I can't even see the installation with a Ubuntu Live CD.

Is there anyway to repair this or did I just completely screw myself?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix

**NOTE:** You cannot recover Windows now but you can try to get the data from Data recovery softwares

**EDIT:** Step - 6

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I don't care to recover Windows but would like to recover my Ubuntu installation and files.  I know the partition is still there since I didn't delete it and when I go to the Windows installation, it shows the partition as "extended".

Comment: Okay so I'm currently at step 6 and not sure what the guide means by "select with boot".  If someone could help me with this before I mess up even more, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I suppose it lists the partitions. Select the partition on which windows is installed.

Comment: Hey Fourtheye.  I see the partition and I get to this step - then select the broken partition with [Boot], it will display something like :

Comment: not sure what type to select for this though.

Comment: Type the partition name there

Comment: I see the partition and I get two options to choose from: "type" and "create image".  I'm confused here, sorry for being clueless about all this...

Comment: This would yield better results if this is continued on chat and the results posted here, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yup. But Draz doesnt have enough rep to join a chat, I think

Comment: SO I go into type and there is a list of choices.  You guys know which to select?

Comment: under >List of partition type

Comment: Werent you getting something similar to what I have posted in the answer?

Comment: Thanks again Fourtheye.  Unfortunately I don't have a boot option?  I only see "Type" and "Image Creation".

Comment: The partition is named 1 E extended and I also see 5 L Linux Swap

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot like I did, to your question?

Comment: I'm typing this from my other computer while I try to fix it.  My screen is exactly like your screenshot except at the bottom there is no "boot" "list" or "undelete".  I just have "Type" "Image Creation" and "Quit" as options.

Comment: 1 sec let me take a screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need 10 rep to post an image.

Comment: You can upload the image to free image hosting services and share the link here

Comment: Here we go imgur.com/pz4PUdd

Comment: Yours is little complicated. Try this http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Current_partition_table_status

Comment: Yea, it only finds my extended Ubuntu partition and the deleted Windows NTFS.  Very confused and tired.  Thanks for the help Fourtheye.  If you have any other suggestions please post and I will check later.

Comment: Did search returned other partitions as well? Can you please post another screenshot?

Comment: Yes it returned the Windows partition, but said it is unrecoverable.

Comment: Anyways, I'm off to bed.  Too tired, can't think.  Will post if I find anything else later on.

Comment: So I'm able to see all my files in the extended partition.  I could copy them out, but I currently don't have an extended drive so this is going to be a problem.  It is about 40GB of data.  Is there any other way to make this extended partition detectable?

Comment: Please consider moving this to chat. Comments are not meant for extended discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you'd deleted the partition that grub was installed on it. so you may use bootrepair to repair your grub installation and update the grub. boot your system with live ubuntu cd (or usb) and then install and use boot repair as https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair 2nd option suggests. it would repair your ubuntu installation. but when you install windows on your system, it would disturb it again and you should use bootrepair again to correct the boot options

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mohammadh.  Unfortunately, when I run boot-repair it doesn't give me an option to repair it, only to create a log.

Comment: Looking over the log, this is the error I am receiving - Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!